# Has something changed in the past 20 years that would yield this compile error on MFC CString.Format?

Tags: c++, mfc, visual-studio-2022

I'm a long time Java/C# developer, and I'm trying to teach myself C++, specifically MFC, using a book by Richard Jones that was published in 2000.

I'm getting this compile error:

> 'ATL::CStringT<wchar_t,StrTraitMFC_DLL<wchar_t,ATL::ChTraitsCRT<wchar_t>>>::Format': no overloaded function could convert all the argument types

On the following code that I typed in from an example in the book:

```cpp
int r;
double rd;
int i;
CString s;

std::cout << "\nLargest random integer: " << RAND_MAX << std::endl;

//Provide seed for generator
srand((unsigned)time(NULL));

std::cout << "\n5 random integers: \n";
for (i = 0; i < 5; i++) {
    r = rand();
    s.Format("%d ", r);  
    std::cout << s << std::endl;
}
```

I'm using Visual Studio 2022, and I'm wondering if I need to configure it differently to use examples from over 20 years ago?

Perhaps related to my confusion, I don't even see a `CString` class listed here: [Walkthrough: Using the New MFC Shell Controls](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/cpp/mfc/walkthrough-using-the-new-mfc-shell-controls?view=msvc-170) - only `CStringArray` and `CStringList`.

As directed in my book, I'm trying to use these MFC classes in a console program as a starting point.  I have my C++ Language Standard set to "Default (ISO C++14 Standard)" in the project properties.  I'm wondering if it would help to set it to whatever the standard was around the year 2000?

Comment: `CString` -> `CStringA` I suspect, with the code as written.  Further reading: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/cpp/atl-mfc-shared/using-cstring?view=msvc-170

Comment: I have a feeling that's the `wchar_t` getting you. Give `s.Format(L"%d ", r);` a try to see if feeding  a wide character format argument makes the compiler happy. Whole <expletive deleted>tons of stuff have changed over the past couple decades. For example, Microsoft typically expects wide characters to be pretty much defacto for any user-facing string and you have to either go with it (usually for the best) or explicitly tell it not to.

Comment: @user4581301 Then the following line will barf.  All ANSI or all Unicode is the way to go, except where a conversion is unavoidable.

Comment: Good point. Go all wide or all ANSI. I recommend going all wide for any serious programs going to customers.

Comment: Don't use a 20 year old book to learn C++. Too much has changed. Especially C++11 was a rather big revolution (evolution really, but it feels bigger) and C++17 and C++20 also added heaps of new and important stuff. A 20 year old book will teach you seriously obsolete C++ - the old stuff still works, sure, we just have so many better ways now that the old stuff is almost considered bad practice these days.

Comment: @user4581301 _go all wide for any serious programs going to customers_ Absolutely.

Comment: To bring you up to speed, try one of these: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/388242/the-definitive-c-book-guide-and-list

Comment: You will do yourself a huge favor by completely forgetting everything about the non-standard `CString` and other key players of Microsoft embrace-and-extend campaigns, and focus on learning standard C++ classes, like `std::string` from a recent C++ textbook.

Comment: "*I don't even see a `CString` class listed here ...*" - of course not, because string classes are not Shell controls. See [Using CString](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/cpp/atl-mfc-shared/using-cstring?view=msvc-170) instead.

Comment: Wow, so much great info here.  Thank you!  Based on some of the responses, I can see that I didn’t make something very clear.  Before this 20 year old MFC book, I read the current edition of “A Tour of C++” and loved it.  In fact, it made me realize that (today’s) C++ is a fabulous, modern language.  My only prior experience (with C or C++) was with C, over 20 years ago.  So, the thing I didn’t make clear is that I’m trying to learn how to write desktop GUI apps in C++ that don’t need .Net.  I’m assuming MFC is still relevant.  If anyone can recommend an MFC book, I would be very grateful.

Comment: Side note: Even 20 years ago C++ and C were pretty different, but massive numbers of students, myself included, were horribly underserved by being taught C programming and very little C++ programming in C++ courses. This continues to this day.

Comment: On the off chance that some other budding C++ GUI developer finds themselves here, my advice would be, don't bother with MFC initially.  One of the responses to my question, lead me to theForger's Win32 API Tutorial (http://winprog.org/tutorial/), and I'm discovering you can write basic GUI's w/ just this.

Comment: Your `s.Format("%d ", r);` line should be `s.Format(_T("%d "), r);` or `s.Format(L"%d ", r);` . I can explain you more after you try it.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

By default, the character set in visual studio is set to Unicode which is why you're getting the error.

To resolve the issue, follow the below steps:

1. Go to Project --> [your_Project_Name] Properties:

[image]

2. Under Configuration Properties, select "Advanced":

[image]

3. Finally, on the right window, click on "character set" and select "not set":

[image]

Click ok, and your code should compile.

Required *include* files:

```
#include <atlstr.h>
#include <iostream>       
#include <ctime>
```

Comment: You nailed it.  Thank you.

Comment: Making a problem go away and solving a problem are not necessarily the same thing. This proposed solution falls into the *"making the problem go away"* bucket and is literally as bad as what the OP started out with.